# Unable to connect to EC2 instance from windows

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, pem

I am on windows 10. I have launched an EC2 instance on AWS and downloaded pem file for it.
I am trying to connect to the instance from terminal. When I run command:

```
ssh -i "mykey.pem" ec2-user@<ip>
```

I get error:

```
Permissions for 'mykey.pem' are too open.
It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.
Load key "mykey.pem": bad permissions
<ip>: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
```

Based on some online suggestions, I ran following command for the key file using cygwin:

```
chmod 400 mykey.pem
```

But I still see same error.

What do I need to get it working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows don't accept creating 400 permissions in its filesystem. If you'll try to do that it'll automatically switch to 555. Use Putty to connect to your EC2 linux instance on AWS.

Here are steps for AWS docs on how to do that
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/putty.html

Comment: There is a way to do 400 mode permission in Windows too. Please see @Basanta KC 's Answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your pem file > Right Click > Select Properties > Go to Security Tab > Click On Advanced. Then you will see this UI

[image]

Then remove all the entries from the permission entries.
If you are unable to remove the entries because of inheritance click on the button called disable inheritance and then remove all the entries.

Then click on Add button > Select Principal > Click On Object Type > Only Select Users > Click OK > Then Click On Advanced button > Find Now > then select the user ( the user here should be the same as the owner of the pem file ) > Give him all the permissions > and apply all the changes
[image]
[image]
Click OK after selecting users only
[image]
Make sure you select the owner of the file in my case BASANTA KC
[image]
Give the permission. ok & apply then :)
[image]

Comment: Thanks for providing Steps to change the permissions in Windows  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Could you try viewing the permissions with `ls -l` and see if it has the appropriate permissions.

Could you also try the following:

1. Right click on the mykey.pem file and click on security and remove all permissions.
2. Also click on Advanced & Disable inheritance.
3. Then give the appropriate permissions and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Window User: I am unable to connect EC2 instance using correct .pem file from Window 11 or 10 that is perfectly working on Ubuntu 22.x.
While trying to connect using ssh -i <file.pem> user@ then getting permission denied issue.

this problem is because of .pem file permission should be 400. Window will not have chmod command.
Window 11 or 10 support have [icacls.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/icacls) command to change file permissions and mode [Read/write/execute].

**How to solve issue:**

```
    Step 1: Open PowerShell or Command Prompt with Admin permission and run commands step by step
    Step 2: icacls.exe rajeevm16oct2021.pem /reset
    Step 3: icacls.exe rajeevm16oct2021.pem /grant:r <windowUserName>:r
       Example: icacls.exe rajeevm16oct2021.pem /grant:r tomcruise:r
    Step 4: icacls.exe rajeevm16oct2021.pem /inheritance:r

response of successful command: 
    processed file: rajeevm16oct2021.pem
    Successfully processed 1 files; Failed processing 0 files


Now Close Powershell or CMD and try to connect with EC2
ssh -i rajeevm16oct2021.pem ubuntu@<EC2InstanceIP>
```